Vue js 2 how to return filtered array from Parent to Child component by replacing the current array prop
I am using Vuejs 2. I have a child component from which I am emiting an event,
Child code
this.$emit("remove-blocked-user-posts", blockedUserName);

In parent, I have post array prop which I am passing to the child. I am receiving the event in parent,
parent code
 props: {
        posts: Array,
        .....
    }

.......

 methods: {
      removeBlockedUserPosts(blockedUserName){

        const postData = this.posts.filter(
            (post) => post.userName !== blockedUserName
        );
      
        //Here is how to set the filtered postData to the Post array prop ?
       // how to set this filtered value to the Post prop array with
      // this.$set(someobject, 'key', 'value')
        
    }

I need to set the filtered post by replacing the current Post array prop to pass to the child component. But I can't do it with this.$set. I need to pass only the filtered array from the parent.

Not sure when you do call removeBlockedUserPosts, but you could have it as a computed rather. What do you see emitted in your Vue devtools, is it the proper payload? .filter is not mutating so that's good, no need to backup the props elsewhere. Once all of this is done, what do you have in postData? Also, where do you listen to the remove-blocked-user-posts event? You cannot call a method with that alone. Please refer to the docs again: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events

postData with filtered post removing post with blockedusername. Just need to know how to set  this.$set

$set is not the issue here, refer to my previous comment.

remove-blocked-user-posts listened on parent , emitted from child .On parent @remove-blocked-user-posts="removeBlockedUserPosts"

Okay, so where's the issue exactly? What do you have in the end in postData? Is it the desired filtered result?

child is not reactive, I mean filtered posts not passing to the child, maybe need set or something. As all posts are passing from parent to child, now it should pass only the filtered posts

Yes, postData has the filtered posts. Those should show on the child instead of all posts .

.filter does not mutate. Hence, if you want to update the props you gonna need to have something like this.posts = this.posts.filter because postData is only local so far.

Yeah, with this.post = this.post.filter is not reactive, only reactive when I set something with this.$set(........).Now I need to know how to set this.post to this.$set , I mean the whole filtered array to this.$set

Hm, do you still need that syntax there since you overwrite the whole array? This is when you need to use $set and they do not apply here. There is probably some other issue. What do you see in your VueJS devtools? Do you have an ESlint warning of any sort?

55:9   warning  Prop 'posts' requires default value to be set

this.post = this.posts.filter(...) is ok you are saying , problem elsewhere

The issue is the reactivity right? Mind submitting a [repro]?

Give me some time

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can't (should not) reassign new values to a prop. If you encounter this situation, you need to re-emit the value from the parent to its grand-parent component until you reach the component where you've defined posts.
Depending on your needs. I'd do the filtering by a some reactive state.
So in your parent components removeBlockedUserPosts method, you can emit another event:
removeBlockedUserPosts(blockedUserName){
  this.$emit('block-username', blockedUserName)
}

You should then have somewhere defined posts in a grand-parent:
<template>
  <Parent :posts="filterdPosts" @block-username="onBlockUsername" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'GrandParent',
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      blockedUsername: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredPosts() {
      return this.blockedUsername ? this.posts.filter(p => p.userName !== this.blockedUserName) : this.posts
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetchPosts()
  },
  methods: {
    fetchPosts() {...},
    onBlockUsername(username) {
      this.blockedUserName = username
    }
  }
}
</script>

